# Django Rest Framework - Uploading files link 404

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to upload a file (any file) to my rest framework.

At the current time, I'm able to upload the file but unable to click on the generated link for some reason.

This is my **settings.py**:

```
...
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media")
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "site_static")]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

This is my **model.py**:

```
...
class FileUpload(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    user_profile = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    datafile = models.FileField(blank=False, null=False)
```

This is my **views.py**:

```
...
class FileUploadViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """Handles uploading a file"""
    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)
    serializer_class = (serializers.FileUploadSerializer)
    queryset = models.FileUpload.objects.all()
    parser_classes = (MultiPartParser, FormParser,)
    permission_classes = (
        permissions.UpdateOwnStatus,
        IsAuthenticated
    )

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        """Sets the user profile"""
        serializer.save(user_profile=self.request.user,
                        datafile=self.request.data.get('datafile'))
```

This is my **serializer.py**:

```
...
class FileUploadSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    user_profile = serializers.SlugRelatedField(
        read_only=True,
        slug_field='id'
    )

    class Meta:
        model = models.FileUpload
        fields = ('id', 'user_profile', 'created', 'datafile')
        extra_kwargs = {'user_profile': {'read_only': True},
                        'created': {'read_only': True}}
```

This is my complete **urls.py**:

```
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register('hello-viewset', views.HelloViewSet, basename='hello-viewset')
router.register('profile', views.UserProfileViewSet)
router.register('feed', views.UserProfileFeedViewSet)
router.register('upload', views.FileUploadViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    path('hello-view/', views.HelloApiView.as_view()),
    path('login/', views.UserLoginApiView.as_view()),
    path('', include(router.urls)),
]

urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

When I upload a file, the **datafile** field becomes populated with the file location, such as:

```
   {
        "id": 2,
        "user_profile": 4,
        "created": "2020-04-27T21:08:16.269058Z",
        "datafile": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/test.png"
    },
```

I look at the project files and I can find the file at /media/, however, the link does not work.

How can I make the link work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem, as it turns out, is that I was editing the wrong urls.py.

Both the api folder and the project folder has urls.py.

When adding that urlpattern to the correct project urls.py, it works fine!

Answer (score 0):

quoted from the docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/)

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: Isn't that the same as the way I did it? `urlpatterns +=` is literally adding to urlpatterns

Comment: I don't think I saw the last 2 lines when I read the question, Mb, gonna delete the answer